# Probability independent events. Please check my answer

Tags: probability

Events $A$ and $B$ are independent. Suppose event $A$ occurs with probability $0.71$ and event $B$ occurs with probability $0.43$.

1.If event $A$ or event $B$ occurs, what is the probability that $A$ occurs?

2.If event $B$  occurs, what is the probability that $A$ does not occur?

Round your answers to at least two decimal places.

I tried to calculate it:
1.P(B|A∪B)=P(B)∩P(A∪B)/(A∪B) =0.43*(0.71+0.43-(0.71*0.43))/((0.71+0.43-(0.71*0.43))=0.43

2.P(B|A')=P(B|A')/P(A')=(0.43*(1-0.71))/0.23=1247/2300

Is this correct?

Comment: There are four possible conditions. The probability that A occurs and B didn't; that A didn't and B did; that A and B both occurred; and that neither occurred. You are told it is one of the first three. So the sum of those three is what you use to normalize with. The probability of A is what gets normalized. You know the answer should be at least A but perhaps more. You should be able to work out the divisor used to normalize, easily.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused.  In the first question you are given that $A$ or $B$ occurs.  That is, $A\cup B$ occurs.  So you want to calculate $P(B|A\cup B).$  Then you say $P(A|B)=P(A|B)/P(B).$  This makes no sense at all, because $P(A|B)$ occurs on both sides.  It could only be true if $P(B)=1,$ or $P(A|B)=0.$

The definition is $\boxed{P(X|Y)=P(X\cap Y)/P(Y)}$ provided $P(Y) \ne 0.$

Try these again with the correct formulas.

Comment: P(B|A∪B)=P(B)∩P(A∪B)/(A∪B) =0.43*(0.71+0.43-(0.71*0.43))/((0.71+0.43-(0.71*0.43))

Is this step correct?

Comment: No it isn't.  You don't mean $P(B)\cap P(A\cup B).$  The two probabilities are numbers, and you can't intersect them.  But I'm not just talking about proper notation.  You want $P(B\cap(A\cup B))$, and $B\cap(A\cup B)=B.$  Also, let me suggest that instead of sticking all these numbers in your formulas, you compute the individual pieces separately and substituting.  What you have written is hard to follow and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(A | A\cup B) = P(A \cap (A\cup B)) / P(A\cup B) = P(A)/P(A \cup B)$$ $$=0.71/(0.71 + 0.43 - 0.71*0.43)$$

For 2, if A $\perp B$, $P(A^{c}|B) = P(A^{c})$

Comment: For 2 is it the answer is 1-0.71=0.29 or 1-answer from(1)= 1247/8347?

Comment: @johnc - Independence means that the behavior of A is not influenced by any function purely of B (including identity function). The case 1 is not an independent case, as you ask "what is the probability that A happened if I told you A or B happened?"

Comment: No clue, I am very bad at probabilities

Comment: Could you please check the final answer for 
1.7100/8347
2. 29/100

Please check